# Addition of two lines massively increases execution times and file size - any idea what's going on?

Tags: c++, file-io, g++

I was tasked with a very simple assignment for my first CS project: take two files, one containing student data and the other a list of courses at my college, and match the two in a third file. When course numbers and subject data in the student file matches identical data in the course list, append course hours and a special code from the course list to each line. All of this is outputted in the third file.

Everything was going dandy when I used the below:

```
   while (sdStream >> eiD >> semester >> subject >> coursenumSD >> grade >> gradeNum) // while stream from SD file is open, execute below
   {
      hcStream.clear();
      hcStream.seekg(0);
      while (hcStream >> subjectHC >> coursenumHC >> gpaHC >> codeHC) // while stream from HC file is open, execute below 
      {
         if ((coursenumHC == coursenumSD) && (subject == subjectHC)) // while identifying info from file 1 = date from file 2, out put the below
         {
            outputStream << endl << eiD + '\t' << semester + '\t' << subject + '\t' << coursenumSD + '\t' << grade + '\t' << gradeNum + '\t' << gpaHC + '\t' << codeHC + '\t';
         }

      }   
   }
```

This bit of code executes in around 39-40 seconds, and yields a file of around 240 kb. I'm compiling this code on Ubuntu running in a VM (parallels) on my 2015 Macbook Retina. I'm using g++.

It turns out that not every line of the student data files corresponds to a course in the course list file. In the event that happens, we are to output the line anyway and provide stock course hours of 3.0 and a special code of RNL. Here is the amended code below:

```
   while (sdStream >> eiD >> semester >> subject >> coursenumSD >> grade >> gradeNum) // while stream from SD file is open, execute below
   {
      hcStream.clear();
      hcStream.seekg(0);
      while (hcStream >> subjectHC >> coursenumHC >> gpaHC >> codeHC) // while stream from HC file is open, execute below 
      {
         if ((coursenumHC == coursenumSD) && (subject == subjectHC)) // while identifying info from file 1 = date from file 2, out put the below
         {
            outputStream << endl << eiD + '\t' << semester + '\t' << subject + '\t' << coursenumSD + '\t' << grade + '\t' << gradeNum + '\t' << gpaHC + '\t' << codeHC + '\t';
         }
         else
         {
            outputStream << endl << eiD + '\t' << semester + '\t' << subject + '\t' << coursenumSD + '\t' << grade + '\t' << gradeNum + '\t' << "3.0" + '\t' << "RNL" + '\t';
         }
      }   
   }
```

This code takes forever. As I've waited upwards of 7 minutes and it's still chugging. I end up terminating the execution because the outputted file is often 400mbs and growing, so clearly I've got some kind of infinite loop or some other oddity. I've tried variations of the condition:

```
else (!(coursenumHC == coursenumSD) && (subject == subjectHC))
```

But I get similar errors. Any idea why there would be such a huge difference in executiontimes and file size?

NOTE: I am new to stackoverflow and I'm still learning how to avoid being verbose and tedious but also descriptive and thorough. If this question is unclear or inadequate, please don't hesitate to upbraid me with suggestions on how I can improve.

EDIT 1: I'm still new to CS, so I mistakenly used compile time when I really meant to say that the amount of time it took for my executable file to run increased. Basically, when I run the executable it takes much longer (actually indefinitely) when the second block of code above.

Comment: replace `endl` with `'\n'` for some instant speedup

Comment: @Chris 1. What is the size of the input files? 2. What is the rate of `if` vs `else` path being taken? If it's very low, of course it will write much more into the output file than the first version, and with flushing - `std::endl`.

Comment: You probably should *profile* your code to find out where the time is being spent. If you suspect an infinite loop then you could add some debugging output lines so that you can check if the execution flow is doing what you expected.  40 seconds for processing 240k of text seems extremely slow (40 milliseconds would be closer to what I'd expect)

Comment: @LogicStuff File 1 (student data) is 190kb, and File 2 (course data) is 273kb. File 1 consists of 6k lines and File 2 of 13k lines. I will experiment with M.M's suggestion to replace endl with \n - I actually totally forgot that endl also flushes.

Comment: Make a small example input with just a few lines and step through the code with a debugger.